Need help understanding how the xycoord axes system works in matplotlib
I am always confused on how to annotate things in matplotlib and doing a deeper dive and discovered the magical world of the different coordinate systems that exist in matplotlib, but I am having trouble understanding it all.
Starting with the axes system, when annotating this is what I got so far:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)


ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,1000)
# -- Annotations --------------------------------

#coordinate system same as data xy = (100,1000)
ax.annotate(
    xy=(80,800),
    text='*1 -data',
    ha='left', va='top',
    xycoords="data" 
)
#coordinates system xy = (0,1) from the axes
ax.annotate(
    xy=(0.5,1.1),
    text='*2 - axes fraction',
    ha='left', va='top',
    xycoords='axes fraction'  
)

#combine data and axes fraction
ax.annotate(
    xy=(30,0.5), #x = 30 and y is the middle of y axes
    text='*3 -data, axes fraction',
    ha='left', va='top',
    xycoords=('data','axes fraction')  
)

#coordinates system xy = (?,?) from the axes
ax.annotate(
    xy=(50,50),
    text='*4 - axes points',
    ha='left', va='top',
    xycoords='axes points' 
)

#coordinates system xy = (?,?) from the axes
ax.annotate(
    xy=(750,750),
    text='*5 - axes pixels',
    ha='left', va='top',
    xycoords='axes pixels'  
)

#annotation for the points coordinate system and xy locations.
t = "Footnotes:\n(1) data, coord @ (100,1000), plotted @ (80,800)\n(2) axes fraction, coord @ (0,1), plotted @ (0.5,1.1)\n(3) data,axes points combined, coord @ x=(0,100), y=(0,1) plotted @ (30,0.5)\n(4) axes points coord @ (?,?) plotted @ (50,50)\n(5)axes pixels, coord @ (?,?) plotted @ (750,750)"
ax.annotate(
    xy=(0,-0.1),
    text = t,
    ha = "left", va= "top", color = "grey",
    xycoords = "axes fraction"
)

Which generates this:

Obviously, I have read the documentation but still not clear on this points:

Why when I specify xy coordintates outside the axes (example 2), it still gets plotted? I would have expected to have to use annotation_clip.

What are the coordinates for the axes points system? Completely lost on this one.

What are the coordinates for the axes pixel system? I know the figure is 1500x1500 but how does that translate into the axes? I didnt expect example 5 to be plotted there.



I think that the documentation clearly explains everything. Here is a link that can help you with different demos

What are the coordinates for the axes points system? Completely lost on this one.
For axes points, see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/207
A point is 1/72 of an inch. You specified 300 dpi, which is 300 pixels per inch - I think this is not technically correct, but it seems to work^{TM}. You placed an annotation at (50,50) in axes points. This is 50/72 of an inch, or 50/72*300 pixels from (0,0).
What are the coordinates for the axes pixel system? I know the figure is 1500x1500 but how does that translate into the axes? I didnt expect example 5 to be plotted there.
Axes pixels are just axes pixels counting from the bottom left (0,0). It's not immediately obvious because of the annotation you've chosen, but if you annotate e.g. using only a minus sign twice: one left, one right adjusted, both vertically centred, you should see that the point is 750 pixels along.
ax.annotate(xy=(750, 750), text="-", ha="left", va="center", xycoords="axes pixels")
ax.annotate(xy=(750, 750), text="-", ha="right", va="center", xycoords="axes pixels")


Thanks! If I plot 50/72*300 using pixel axes it shows in the same position so it makes sense!
Regarding the pixel axes explanation, plotted both annotations but I still dont understand how 750 works? as the figure is 1500 by 1500 is the axes also the same? and in that case I would expect it to be in the middle but it shows a bit to the right? Still confused I am afraid. With figure axes it gets placed in the middle.
What am I missing?

750 pixels is counted from the axes origin, i.e. point (0,0). The position of that would not be in the middle, but it would be offset by the amount of pixels to the left and below the axes.

ok, how do I find out the middle of the axes or how do I know how much is the offset? Thanks for you patience btw

Sorry, unsure how to do it programmatically with pixel counts. That's where all the other various coordinate systems come in (axes fraction for this particular case).

Last question, promise! What would be then a good case for axes pixels? Maybe it is not used a lot?

When annotating a photograph, or a medical image for example. You will know the pixel coordinates of any feature in the image outside of Python, and then you can use those external pixel coordinates to annotate the image in Python with axes pixels.
